# Blueprint read value from configuration file

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, blueprint

I have a Blueprint.xml, and i need read values from an external configuration file (in this example the value to put in _from1):

```
....

 <camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <route id="cbr-route">

             <from id="_from1" uri="ftp://user@localhost:21/files?password=pass"/>   


            <to id="_to1" uri="file:c:/TestFTP"/>

        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [property place holder](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html) functionality in apache camel. The apache camel site has a lot of information around using this, however I will just step through the basics so you can fill in the gaps with the more expanded documents. You are also using blueprint which is different from the old Spring place holders. Essentially this a key value type syntax with some gotchas to be aware of.

**1. Format/Syntax Of Property Place Holders In blueprint.xml:**

The value of a  property can be obtained by specifying its key name within a property placeholder using the following syntax/format `{{key}}`.

For example to specify a server address you could use `{{server.ip}}`.

**2. Using the Property Resolver:**

You can store the values of the property place holders in various places thus you need to specify how to resolve them. This is done by using the PropertyResolver prefix:

```
    Prefix       Description
    ref:         Lookup in the Registry.
    file:        Load the from file system.
    classpath:   Load from the classpath(default if no provider specified)
    blueprint:   Use a specific OSGi blueprint placeholder service.
```

**3. Add the CM namespace to the blueprint.xml**

Change your blueprint XML to include the CM namespace.

Thus change from:

```
 <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
```

To:

```
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
```

**Some examples and notes:**

The example below declares three property place holders namely the mail server name, the mail from and the mail to properties. Some things to note that I am declaring this without a property resolver thus it will look for it on the classpath. I deploy most of my routes on karaf, servicemix thus I created a company.info.cfg file which I placed in my karaf/etc folder.  Lets look at the blueprint below and see how things tie up. Read the XML comments.

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd         http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

<!-- NOTE: The system will look for a file called company.info.cfg in the classpath, this is the value specified by  persistent-id="company.info". -->

<cm:property-placeholder id="placeholder.company.info" persistent-id="company.info"  update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="company.division.name" value="Foobab"/>
        <cm:property name="company.division.mail.host" value="foobab-mail-1-server"/>
        <cm:property name="company.division.mail.to"   value="foo@bab.com"/>
        <cm:property name="company.division.mail.from" value="foobabCamelServer@bab.com"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<camelContext id="rmsConfirmedClosedAccountContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <endpoint id="smtpFoobabReport" uri="smtp://{{company.division.mail.host}}?to={{company.division.mail.to}}&amp;from={{company.division.mail.from}}&amp;contentType=text/html"/><!-- Here we use a property placeholder For The Mail server-->
      
    <route id="timerHelloRoute">
        <from id="fromTimerFoobab" uri="timer:Foobab"/>
        <setHeader headerName="subject" id="setCompanySubjectHeader">
            <constant>Foobab reminder for:{{company.division.name}}</constant> <!-- Here we use a property placeholder to set the subject-->
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="body" id="setMailBOdy">
            <constant>The company needs to view its foobab report</constant> 
        </setHeader>
        <to id="toSmtpFoobabReport" ref="smtpFoobabReport"/>
</camelContext>
```

You would also notice that I have supplied the property placeholder with default values. This is very useful during development and even during go live as camel will try to find the properties file and if it cant then it will use the defaults thus you could point your default values to development and keep the production values in the config file far away from the dev box.

One last things before a more complicated example is the file and the update_strategy tag. A typical config file would contain value like this:

```
company.division.name = foobabababa
company.division.mail.host = production.mail
```

If your update_strategy is set to reload like my example if you changed the value of the cfg file then it would reload the routes which point to this configuration. Dynamic properties no need to stop and start your routes.

Now sometimes you will need to have more than one properties file to be used in a system. For example a email properties file and a database properties file.

To do this you need to be aware that you need to change the propertyplaceholder syntax/format for the second, third etc's files.

Only the first property file can use `{{some.value}}`. This needs to be done when declaring the properties place holders. See below for an example:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="UpdateFilesProperties" persistent-id="maintenance.files.cfg" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="washPool.size" value="1"/>
        <cm:property name="sifPool.size" value="1"/>
        <cm:property name="updatePool.size" value="1"/>
        <cm:property name="etlJobPool.size" value="1"/>
        <cm:property name="etlSplitPool.size" value="1"/>
        com.au"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
<cm:property-placeholder id="ccompany.info" persistent-id="info"
    placeholder-prefix="$([" placeholder-suffix="])" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <!--    properties  -->
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

So the first set of properties would be access like `{{washPool.size}}` however the second set of properties would use the syntax specified by these attributes   `placeholder-prefix="$([" placeholder-suffix="])"` thus `([key.value])`.

They are incredibly powerful. I have used them to configure the number of threads on a route for example which allowed me to tune the performance based on feedback without recompiles and redeployments.

Comment: Than you for the reply.
Me correct question is, if I deploy this app in Apache Fuse, how modify in fly this properties.

Thank you.

Comment: @JoseVázquez you mean JBoss Fuse? JBoss Fuse is a red hat certified servicemix. It also uses Apache karaf. So in your JBOSS Fuse home path you should find an etc directory something like /opt/jboss_fuse/etc. Store your configuration files there. You can open the files edit them and save them and Fuse will pick up the change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cm:property-placeholder.

Please check 
Using a .cfg or .properties File For Blueprint Property Placeholders section in [1]

There is an option update-strategy which can be set to reload and the new properties added or overridden will reflect.

[1] http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html